# Annoying job suggestion

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

This is probably a case , however, I find particularly annoying to receive application recommendations from the company in which I am already employed.

[image]

This has been happening for some time, and this example is just the latest in a long line at the moment I can not document.
It would not be possible exclude from companies tips to which we are somehow connected?
Is there any reason to do this is impractical?